# Angular How to implement Subject instead of Input and template variable

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs

EDIT:
I implemented some logic to hide my icons and how them only when a specific row from parent component is on mouseover. I need to adjust this logic to my project. Changing global styles is unfortunately unacceptable in my project :(
I tried to implement it with Subject, but now instead of current row, all rows are affaected and all icons are shown. Is it possible to use these Subject Operator logic and show icons only on curretnly hovered row?
This is now my parent component HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!emptyList else emptyListTemplate">
                            <tr requestRow *ngFor="let request of requests"
                                (mouseenter)="emitEventToChild(true)"
                                (mouseleave)="emitEventToChild(false)"
                                [isRequestRowHighlighted]="eventsSubject.asObservable()"
                                [attr.data-cy-request-id]="request.id"
                                [request]="request"
                                [actionable]="true"
                                [isRequest]="isRequestsList"
                                (delete)="deleteRequest($event)"
                                appMemoTooltip>
                            </tr>
                        </ng-container>
```

This is the TS part:

```
isMouseEnter: boolean
eventsSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

emitEventToChild(e: boolean) {
    this.eventsSubject.next(e)
}

private filterSubscription: Subscription
```

This is my child component HTML (its selector is 'tr[requestRow]' )

```
<td *ngIf="actionable" class="p-auto text-center actions" (mouseenter)="memoControls.pause()" (mouseleave)="memoControls.resume()">
<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end" [ngClass]="{'invisible': !isMouseEnter}">
    <button
        *ngIf="preferredEditType"
        type="button" class="btn btn-primary bg-transparent border-0"
        title="Edit"
        data-cy-id="cy-btn-edit"
        (click)="load($event, request, isRequest, preferredEditType)">
        <i class="icon-edit-request"></i>
    </button>
    <button *ngIf="hateoas.supports(request, 'details')"
            type="button" class="btn btn-success bg-transparent border-0"
            title="Reuse"
            data-cy-id="cy-btn-reuse"
            (click)="load($event, request, isRequest, requestOperationType.REUSE)">
        <i class="icon-copy"></i>
    </button>
    <button *ngIf="hateoas.supports(request, 'delete')"
            type="button" class="btn btn-danger bg-transparent border-0"
            title="Delete"
            data-cy-id="cy-btn-delete"
            (click)="deleteRequest($event)">
        <i class="icon-trash"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

This is the TS file:

```
@Input() isRequestRowHighlighted: Observable<boolean>
isMouseEnter: boolean
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.eventsSubscription = this.isRequestRowHighlighted.subscribe(value => this.isMouseEnter = value)}
enter code here
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.eventsSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSBlH.png)

[As is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwmjR.png)

Please, let me know how can I achieve displaying icons only for current(on mouseenter) row, not for all of them.
Thank you.

Comment: why not use a simple css? `tr:hover td button{visibility:hidden}`

Comment: It does not work with CSS. I already tried from both components

Comment: the .css to mannage two differents components should be global

Answer (score 0):

the .css to mannage two differents components should be global, so try in **styles.css**

```
tr[requestRow] button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
tr[requestRow]:hover button{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

A Simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hbqg2v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Update**

Well, we can use a [ViewEncapsulation.None](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation), who apply all the .css in our component in a way global.

```
@Component({
  selector: [requestRow]
  ...
  encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

But **be carefull**, if in our component we use also e.g. `h1{color:red}` this style is also propagate to all our aplication

Another way (**but is marked as deprecated**) is using some like (in parent.css)

```
:host ::ng-deep tr[hello]  button {
  visibility:hidden
}
:host ::ng-deep tr[hello]:hover button{
  visibility:visible
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is amazing and works but I cannot edit styles.scss in my company. I edited my question. Please, have a look if you can

Comment: @Artamiel, you can use also ViewEncapsulation.None (it's a way to say Angular that all the .css of the component is applied to al the app or use the **deprecated** :host ::ng-deep (Personally I don't like this solution)